# What is the difference between constexpr and non-constexpr lookup table in runtime usage?

Tags: c++, assembly, compiler-optimization, constexpr

I have a lookup table values of which I know at compile time, but I want to use it in runtime. Lets say I have an enum:

```
enum class Types : uint8_t {
      Char
    , Int
};
```

And I want a table which contains sizes of these types. I know the values at compile time: `char` - 1, `int` - 4. And as an example I parse a file with a struct containing these types and calculate its total size. My objective is to get rid of `if` and `switch` statements like this:

```
if (type == Types::Char) {
    sum += 1;
} else if (type == Types::Int) {
    sum += 4;
}
```

And would like to have something like this:

```
sum += typeSizes[type];
```

I can't use template in this case, because I need `operator[]`, so that's where I started to think if constexpr here will make any difference. Does the compiler store this table in memory or it is hardcoded in code? If first assumption is correct then what is the difference from usual runtime memory? And if second one is correct then how does it handle taking the right value?

I tried to compile the following code on godbolt (gcc 11.2 -O3):

```
constexpr int a[] = {5, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1};
```

If this variable is accessed only in compile time then it is not even in the assembly (which is fair). But if I have a runtime access then the following code is being generated:

```
.LC0:
        .long   5
        .long   2
        .long   4
        .long   4
.LC1:
        .long   2
        .long   1
```

I would assume that the code just jumps to the right value, but it seems like it just copies values to memory and then the right value is accessed as with runtime memory. Will there actually be any performance gain with constexpr? And if not - is there a way to abuse availability of lookup table values at compile time?

Comment: You understand that something like `.long 5` is not an instruction that gets executed, right? What distinction are you making between “memory” and “runtime memory”?

Comment: @Sneftel I know that it's not an executable instruction. No distinction (memory == runtime memory)

Comment: `constexpr` functions called at runtime are as regular functions. called in constexpr expression, code would just have the result (compiler might "interpret" the code).

Comment: @Jarod42 So the answer is that there's no difference (performs the same as runtime version) with memory as with functions?

Comment: With optimization enabled, usually just `const` or even just `static` is fine to let the compiler do constant-propagation (by figuring out that nothing can change the array), no need for `constexpr` unless it makes the compiler try harder to do constant-propagation at compile time instead of run-time computation.

Answer (score 1):

> Will there actually be any performance gain with constexpr?

Depends on context and what you compare it to. Like you said: *"If this variable is accessed only in compile time then it is not even in the assembly"*. `constexpr` allows the array to be used in compile time constant expressions which allows the array to never be used at runtime. "No assembly" is typically faster than "some assembly".

Comment: Of course, compilers are *allowed* to do the same optimizations on arrays that aren't `constexpr`, if they can prove that nothing ever modifies the array.  Plain `const` can help compilers prove that for global-scope arrays.  Also, in contexts where they're not forced to do compile-time constant propagation (e.g. using the array element as a template param or dimension for another array), with optimization disabled they may *choose* not to (e.g. at `-O0`), even if you do use `constexpr`.  `constexpr` doesn't actually force compile-time eval to be done, just force it to be possible.

Comment: @PeterCordes There's no difference between const variable with constant initialiser, and constexpr variable as far as I know. But a const variable can have non-constant initialiser, which is generally much harder to optimise for.

Comment: That's another version of what I was trying to say, yes.  It's not `constexpr` itself that makes better asm, it's that using it is a way to verify that your C++ is fully optimizable.